# Warehouse location problem (optimal site selection on undirected graph)

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

**Problem Description:** Assign several warehouses to specific locations in the grid, and find the solution that minimizes the total cost of transportation.
**Known:** Transportation cost per kilometer between two warehouses, a grid-like map, where each edge have a unit weight (1 kilometer)

**Example**: Find locations for five warehouses {A,B,C,D,E}, the transportation cost per kilometer between two warehouses is shown in the following table, the grid-like map is shown in the following figure, each edge of this undirected graph has a length of 1 kilometer. Find the solution that minimizes the total cost of transportation.

[image]

[image]

An nonoptimal solution for instance: such as : `A->0, B->1, C->2, D->3, E->7`, then the total cost = 
`cost(A,B)+cost(A,D)+cost(A,E)+cost(B,C)+cost(B,E)+cost(C,D)+cost(C,E)+cost(D,E)`
 = `10*1+30*3+35*4+40*1+60*3+80*1+90*2+70*1`

**Question**: How to design a polynomial time algorithm to find the optimal solution, or approximately optimal solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "-" in the Table means no transport relationship between the two warehouses

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far and what are the issues you are having. Also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My current algorithm is designed in this way. First, consider the table defining the transport relation as a adjacency matrix. Based on this adjacency matrix, get the corresponding graph. Traverse this graph in a BFS way and record this BFS queue. Then each time retrieve a element from the BFS queue and assign it to a certain location on the map in a greedy way (make the cost  minimum) until the BFS queue is empty.

This algorithm is fast, but the solution we get is far away from optimal.

I need some advice on the algorithm model for this problem.

Comment: @jojo can you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58618009/edit) to include that information? Thanks!